# How to realtime listen data from server without crazy request?

Tags: android

I have Asp.Net server api, and post, get data to/from server. If i want get/post data from server, i send request to it and receive respond -> OK 
But i want to listen to server send to my Android client  without request (or request but not crazy to get realtime data)

I used to use Google Cloud Message but my Tablet not work because it doesn't have Google Play. General, i cannot use GCM although it very good

I used to read about SignalR, but i cannot find any example for Android to use it
Somebody can help me, what library or way to listen data from server, same chat app. 
Thank for your answer!

Comment: Socket.io, try socket connections.

Comment: can you give me some example?

Comment: refer to this link: http://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/

Comment: does it work over internet ?